# Ruby on Rails Zeus Alternative for Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bdd

I want to speed up my application's test suite, which currently takes 13 seconds to run. A friend recommended me to use Zeus, but it doesn't work on Windows. What alternatives are there?

Gemfile

```
group :test do
 gem 'capybara'
 gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.1'
 gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

**Edit:** I looked around some more and the guy who made Spork told me to use Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [RailsCast on Spork](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork)

From the video:

"Spork improves the loading time of your test suite by starting up your Rails application once in the background. Use it with Guard for the ultimate combo."

Answer (score 0):

you can try [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) as an alternative for `Zeus`

Spork is Tim Harper's implementation of test server (similar to the script/spec_server that used to be provided by rspec-rails) and It also runs on windows.